# Handle ' while updating content SQL query

Tags: mysql

I Have a sql query :-

```
"""UPDATE table SET column1 = '%s' WHERE columnId = '%s' """ %(columnContent,columnId)
```

When i'm updating some content like:

`It caters to customers in more than 100 international destinations through its online portals at Macys.com. A major attraction is its events such as Macy's 4th of July Fireworks, Macy's Thanksgiving Day Parade, fashion shows, culinary events, flower shows, celebrity appearances and more.`

Then it gives an error:

`_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's 4th of July Fireworks' at line 1")`

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
"""
   UPDATE table
   SET column1=%s
   WHERE columnId=%s
""", (columnContent, columnId)
```

Comment: I got an error : TypeError: must be string or read-only buffer, not tuple